# DMZ on a different router

Tags: dmz

Is it possible to set a second router as a DMZ host?
Or is it much simpler to set my webserver as the DMZ host?

I'm using two routers on my network and these routers are on different subnets.
My webserver is located on the second router's subnet.

1st router: 192.168.254.254
2nd router: 192.168.2.254

I am thinking on doing this because I want to forward my webserver to the outside world.

Comment: depends on the router topology, your server is not more secure if you do dmz after dmz, so move your server closest to the router with public ip configured